# can not install app on Android 4.0 mini PC using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to install my app on a Android 4.0 mini pc. The problem is when i connect it to my laptop over usb the laptop do not find any new devices. so well i can not upload my app.

i also checked if usb debugging is enabled and if there are any drivers but i can't find anything useful.

perhaps anyone have had the same issue like me and can help?

thank

Comment: Can't you just export your apk file then and test it?
Or use connect to it over WIFI ? (search Adb wifi on googleplay).

Comment: sure i could export the apk but for debuging thats not the best solution. well wifi i will give a try#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use adb over wifi. In Android ICS+ its usually built in, so there is no need to download thirdparty applications to connect adb over wifi. Just check the developeroptions in the settings. Then note your lokal IP Adress and run:

```
adb connect <your ip adress>
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi had the same problem

Found two answers:

1) change the usb cable (Not my problem but known to work)

2) install drivers [32bit](http://www.kmods.net/android/download_file2.php?pid=18) [64bit](http://www.kmods.net/android/download_file2.php?pid=17) found from [blog](http://colonelzap.blogspot.co.nz/2012/01/allwinner-a10-adb-drivers.html) (This one worked for me)

Hope this helps